# VB.NET DateTimePicker range

Tags: vb.net

Or I cannot explain what should be the `appropriate` question for this.... however...

Hi,

I am developing a tax software. I have two `DateTimePicker` controls.

First one is `From` and the second one is `to` i.e. Date From and Date to (not exactly...should be month span).

I need to input in the first `DateTimePicker` and the second one will get the automatic range.

```
DtpTo.Value = DtpFrom.Value.AddMonths(3)
```

Up to this is ok. But now comes the complex thing.

If the user inputs `01/04/2016` in the first, the second `DateTimePicker` will automatically calculate days and display `30/06/2016`. If the user inputs `30/06/2016` in the first, the second `DateTimePicker` must display `30/06/2016`.

i.e. the range will be from `April` to `June`, `July` to `September` and so on. The restriction is whichever date user inputs in the first `DateTimePicker` control, any `code` should detect the `range` and restricts the second `DateTimePicker` to the end of the day of that range.

Like.....

[image: Example]

How should I do this ?

Comment: Why does there need to be a second DTP at all?  If the end date is supposed to be the first plus 3 mos, juts use a label.  Some of your description is muddled: *If the user inputs 30/06/2016 in the first, the second DateTimePicker must display 30/06/2016.* and the range from `01/01/2016` to `30/06/2016` looks like 6 full months not 3

Comment: Hi @Plutonix. Thanks for your quick reply. Sorry for the wrong date. I am editing it. But whether it is a `DateTimePicker` or a `Label`, the date should be displayed.

Comment: i dont understand this . Do you want this?  if Dtpfrom is smaller than half of the year then dtpto must be max last day of june and if its greater then the half of the year then dpto must be last day of the year? 
dpfrom     -     dpto 
(10-01-2016 / 10-03-2016) , 
(20-04-2016 /  20-06-2016) ,( 01-05-2016 / 30-06-2016 ), (01-07-2016,01-10-2016) ?

Comment: Either use a label, either use a second DTP that is `enabled=false` and you update it on event `ValueChanged` of your first DTP

Answer (score 3):

You need to examine the "from" month and figure out what the last month of the quarter is from that. Then you need the last day of that quarter's last month:

```
Sub DtpFrom_ValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DtpFrom.ValueChanged
    Dim dtp = DirectCast(sender, DateTimePicker)
    Dim d = dtp.Value.Date

    Dim maxMonth As Integer
    Select Case d.Month
        Case 1 To 3
            maxMonth = 3
        Case 4 To 6
            maxMonth = 6
        Case 7 To 9
            maxMonth = 9
        Case Else
            maxMonth = 12
    End Select

    DtpTo.Value = New Date(d.Year, maxMonth, DateTime.DaysInMonth(d.Year, maxMonth))

End Sub
```

If it is possible that a quarter includes a year transition, it will be a bit more fiddly.

Answer (score 1):

To get Date To (the last day of the last month of the quarter start date) :

1- Must firstly calculate the quarter of Date from with this function

```
Math.Ceiling(dateFrom.Month / 3.0)
```

*`Math.Ceiling` Returns the smallest integer greater than or equal to the specified number.
Note the function use 3.0 to perform a floating point division and not an integer division*

2- Get last month in trimester by increase the trimster number by 3.

3- Get last day of that quarter's last month

```
Private Sub DtpFromDtpTo_ValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DtpFromDtpTo.ValueChanged

    Dim dateFrom As Date = DtpFrom.Value.Date
    Dim lastMonthInTrimester As Integer = Math.Ceiling(dateFrom.Month / 3.0) * 3
    DtpTo.Value = New DateTime(dateFrom.Year, lastMonthInTrimester, DateTime.DaysInMonth(dateFrom.Year, lastMonthInTrimester))

End Sub
```

You can also get the last month of trimester by:

```
Dim lastMonthInTrimester As Integer = Convert.ToInt16((dateFrom.Month + 1) / 3) * 3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Private Sub DtpFrom_ValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DtpFrom.ValueChanged
    Dim datefrom As Date = DtpFrom.Value
    Dim dateto As Date = Nothing
    If datefrom.AddMonths(3).Month > 6 And datefrom.Month <= 6 Then
        Dim DaysInMonth As Integer = Date.DaysInMonth(datefrom.Year, 6)
        Dtpto.Value = New Date(datefrom.Year, 6, DaysInMonth)
    ElseIf datefrom.AddMonths(3).Month <= 6 And datefrom.Month <= 6 Then
        Dtpto.Value = datefrom.AddMonths(3)
    ElseIf datefrom.AddMonths(3).Month <= 12 And datefrom.AddMonths(3).Month >= 6 And datefrom.Month >= 6 Then
        Dtpto.Value = datefrom.AddMonths(3)
    ElseIf datefrom.AddMonths(3).Month <= 2 And datefrom.AddMonths(3).Month And datefrom.Month >= 6 Then
        Dim DaysInMonth As Integer = Date.DaysInMonth(datefrom.Year, 12)
        Dtpto.Value = New Date(datefrom.Year, 12, DaysInMonth)
    End If



End Sub
```